# How do I prove this statement about even actions?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

Hello I have the following problem:

> We call a group action $\psi:G\times Y\rightarrow Y$ even if forall $y\in Y$ we have that there is an open neighbourhoow $U_y$ such that $$\psi_g(U_y)\cap U_y\neq \emptyset \Leftrightarrow g=id\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)$$ If $G$ acts evenly on a topological space $Y$ via $$\psi:G\times Y\rightarrow Y$$ then also the group $H\subset G$ acts evenly via the restriction of $\psi$ to $H$

I wanted to proof this as follows:

Let us assume that $G$ acts evenly on $Y$ via $$\psi:G\times Y\rightarrow Y$$ i.e. forall $y\in Y$ there exists $U_y$ such that (1) holds.
Let $H\subset G$ a subgroup. Let $y\in Y$ and take $U_y$ as above and consider $$\psi_g:Y\rightarrow Y,\,\,\,y\mapsto g\cdot y$$

$\Leftarrow$ Let us assume that $g=id$. Since $H\subset G$ is a subgroup also $id\in H$. Then from (1) $$\psi_{id}|_H(U_y)\cap U_y=id\cdot U_y\cap U_y\neq \emptyset$$

$\Rightarrow$ Now let us assume that $h\neq id$, then from (1) $$\psi_{h}|_H(U_y)\cap U_y=h\cdot U_y\cap U_y=\emptyset$$
Therefore $H$ acts evenly on the restriction

But I'm not sure if this works. Could someone please help me, I would be very thankful since I have a lot of problems with this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the open neighbourhoods $U_y$ in your definition need to be non-empty. Otherwise $$\operatorname{id}U_y \cap U_y = U_y\cap U_y = U_y = \varnothing.$$

Anyway, it holds that ${\psi}{\mid_H}_{h}(U_y) = \psi_h(U_y)$ for all $h\in H$. Thus $${\psi}{\mid_H}_{\operatorname{id}}(U_y) = \psi_{\operatorname{id}}(U_y)=\operatorname{id}U_y = U_y$$

Therefore $${\psi}{\mid_H}_{\operatorname{id}}(U_y)\cap U_y = \psi_{\operatorname{id}}(U_y)\cap U_y \not= \varnothing$$ by $(1)$.

Now assume $\operatorname{id}\not= h \in H$. As before,

$${\psi}{\mid_H}_{h}(U_y) = \psi_{h}(U_y)=hU_y$$

Thus

$$\psi_{h}(U_y)=hU_y \cap U_y = \varnothing$$ again, due to $(1)$. Right, otherwise there would exist some $h\in H\subset G$ so that $(1)$ is not satisfied. Which would contradict your assumption of $G$ acting evenly on $Y$.

Comment: sorry but I don't see a difference between your any my solution? so is my also correct or do I explicitly need to say that $\psi|H_{id}(U_y)=U_y$

Comment: You have some error in your "$\implies$" since you're still using $\operatorname{id}$ smh.

Comment: So $\rightarrow$ part I show with contraposition

Comment: Sorry I corrected $\Rightarrow$ does it work now?

Comment: Yes, now it's fine.

Comment: and $\Leftarrow$ also works?

Comment: Yes, as i said, provided $U_y\not= \varnothing$.

Comment: Sorry can I ask you something randomly. Are you familiar with the fundamental group? Because I try to understand a problem with the fundamental group but I somhow don't see how this works (we stared this topic last week)

Comment: Yes, i'm familiar with the fundamental group. In order to avoid extended discussions in comments, you should consider asking a separate question anyway.

Comment: Yes so if you don't mind I would ask a new question, maybe you can have a look at it.

Comment: I have posed the new question